# Apple iAd enabled, yes or no?

Tags: app-store-connect, iad

This is awkward.
I am trying to upload my first app to apple, and since it has a free version, I'd like to use iAd services. In the itunesConnect, in order to allow iAd services you'd need to configure ad services. What I find weird UX wise, is that it is not clear if the button enables iAd services, or actually pressing it would enable them?
So is iAd services ON or OFF?

[image]

What even weirder is that the save button would make this somewhat not so easy to undo in case you were mistaken.

Apple is known for their brilliant UX/UI. This is puzzling. Thanks

Comment: I always clicked "Enable iAd Network" and then save. Did you try that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### iAd is currently **off**.

If you want to **use iAd**, then you should **click the button**. If you do **not** want to use iAd, **do not** click the button.

Comment: So, the button should be grey, saying Disable iAd? that's strange, people I ask have 50-50 idea about what it means...

Comment: @Ted Yes. If the blue state of the button said 'iAd enabled, then it would be the other way around. As it is now, the button is for you to take an action, not to find out what the current state is.

Answer (score 2):

If you click the blue iAd Enable button, and then click "save".. that will do the trick. Then just upload the binary through iTunes Connect and you will be good to go.